# Firebase Phone Auth isn't sending SMS with code

Tags: android, firebase, dart, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to set up phone number authentication using Firebase for my Android app. I've enabled phone authentication on the "authentication" tab on Firebase console and added my number for testing. I've tried with multiple numbers but I get no SMS sent to any of them despite the console telling me PhoneCodeSent function was fired and displaying a success message. I've tried to fix it for a while and can't seem to find a solid answer. What's wrong with my code?

My code is the following

```
...
...
...
String verificationId;
int resendingToken;

Future<void> _sendConfirmationCode() async {
if (formKey.currentState.validate()) {
  formKey.currentState.save();

  final PhoneVerificationCompleted verificationCompleted = (FirebaseUser user) {
    setState(() {
      print('verification has been completed');
    });
  };

  final PhoneVerificationFailed verificationFailed = (AuthException authException) {
    setState(() {
      print(countrySelected);
      print(this.phone + "\n");
      print('verification failed error: ' + authException.message);}
    );
  };

  final PhoneCodeSent codeSent = (String verificationId, [int forceResendingToken]) async {
    this.verificationId = await verificationId;
    this.resendingToken = await forceResendingToken;
    print("code sent: "+ verificationId);
  };

  final PhoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout codeAutoRetrievalTimeout =
      (String verificationId) {
    this.verificationId = verificationId;
    print("time out");
  };

  if (this.phone.isNotEmpty) {

    await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: "<PHONE NUMBER HARDCODED HERE>", //I've tried hardcoding my number too but it didn't work
      timeout: const Duration(seconds: 5),
      verificationCompleted: verificationCompleted,
      verificationFailed: verificationFailed,
      codeSent: codeSent,
      forceResendingToken: resendingToken,
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: codeAutoRetrievalTimeout);
  }
 }
}
```

The following gets printed to the console:

```
I/flutter (32425): code sent: AM5PThC4JnFK7czWDoAdqSFjBdDk5oq9VwufNvWxgcOg4fEgbHE8CoYGuWMCjzTnfPbOlpcdfefouwL86dsD5fQs73CcR3NgvI2SRqHEHgM0n34yqqJma75ZCvPGMeTmwy6XDCA9-P0p
I/flutter (32425): time out
```

I've also tried waiting a few hours in case I'd reached Firebase's SMS limit, but that doesn't seem to be the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: is your number formate valid?

Comment: did you add country code before number

Comment: @MuhaiminurRahman Yes, I've added the country code, I've tripled checked everything, I've tried hardcoding the phone number and PhoneCodeSent callback is being fired. I even tried hardcoding a badly formatted number to see if it still fired the callback but I got an error so it's not a formatting issue. I also tried this demo https://fir-ui-demo-84a6c.firebaseapp.com/ to see if maybe was a problem with my phone carrier but it works just fine. I'm still stuck at this.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the `timeout`? Something like `const Duration(seconds: 60)`

Comment: You can check deleting user from Firebase [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53429705/2289835)

Comment: @MuhaiminurRahman,you right! That was my problem

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When you add a phone number for testing, you are basically whitelisting it. Whitelisted phone numbers are used for testing phone number authentication without sending an actual SMS message.

No verification code SMS is sent to whitelisted phone numbers and a default OTP of 123456 (unless you have provided the 6-digit verification code for that specific number when adding to the test console). Try to verify using this code, it will authenticate and generate a valid verification ID.

For getting the SMS, remove your number from the whitelist and try again.

Reference: [https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#test-with-whitelisted-phone-numbers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#test-with-fictional-phone-numbers)

Comment: Thanks this has been really helpful, I tried this and it successfully verifies the phone number along with the verification code. However I'd still like to test Firebase sending me a real SMS. I removed the number from the "User" tab on the "Authentication" subsection as you suggested and got the following message. **"This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verifythat the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase Console."** I've checked and the SHA-1 signature is correctly configured, any ideas?

Comment: @MarcoFregoso try going to https://console.cloud.google.com and checking if `Identity Toolkit API` is ticked (if the key was restricted).

Comment: Hey @Vineet , I just do that but I can't receive anything!! - in a Testing mode "Debugging" you know we write a test verify code and it's work well but after I release my app for Stores I can't get any SMS So should I do something maybe I forget?

Comment: @MarcoFregoso did you get the solution? I'm facing same issue!