# Issue in Phone number authentication in firebase through android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I created an android app where i used phone number based authentication provided by firebase.

When i use any phone number other than mine,they are receiving the OTP many a times/

But for my number alone i am receiving OTP only once a day.

Is it some issue with the setting in firebase?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try to [delete user from firebase.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53429705/2289835) let me know if you have any issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an issue with setting in firebase. Maybe you have used your number more than the limit set by firebase.
I was also getting the issue. In my case, It was due to the overuse of a single mobile number.
You can contact firebase authorities and tell them the issue you are having.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to log out before sending again try this and tell me.
thanks

Comment: I think you should use a comment instead of posting this an answer.