# Firebase Authentication Blocked My Android device

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to register with a firebase phone number. The firebase does not send the verification code when trying to register on my phone. But the firebase is send verification code when trying on another device.

```
private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallBack = new PhoneAuthProvider
        .OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks()
    {

        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(String s, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken)
        {
            super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
            verificationId = s;
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential)
        {
            String code = phoneAuthCredential.getSmsCode();
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Verification code received", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };

// this method does not respond
         try
        {
            PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(number, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS, TaskExecutors.MAIN_THREAD, mCallBack);
        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toasty.error(getApplicationContext(), "OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Comment: You can [delete user from Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53429705/2289835) and then try.

Comment: @RumitPatel The problem is not related to the user, related to the device

Comment: Have you tried using your number with another device?

Comment: Are Google Play Services present and up to date on both devices?